# SQLite Data loss?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

A few months ago I coded in PHP web app that is running with an SQLite DB.

We had at the time, the choice of this SGBD for reasons of performance and technical constraints.

You should know that this base is relatively heavy (currently about 1.3 GB), because I stores especially in base 64 encoded pictures which produces a lot of characters.

I just realized that I have some entries fields incomplete, lost data.

I log all actions made by my users when one of them modifies an entry I keep in memory the old value and the new value in a log table. By analyzing the log base for a particular entry, the logs are good with complete data as my input has lost data. Contrary to the popular saying, the problem does not appear to be between the chair and the keyboard.

I think I may be able to recover my lost data.

However, do you think that the data loss is possible?

If so, what could be the cause?

The choice of this SGBD is it relevant in view of the size of the database (which grows about 100 MB / week)?

Comment: SQLite is one of the most heavily tested and benchmarked ACID databases in the entire galaxy (read: https://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html and https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html). With all due respect, testing your own code would be my starting point, esp. when if you have (a great) many concurrent writes.

Comment: Data loss is possible, the cause is almost certainly an error in your program.